# Пропадает весь контент при деактивации плагина polylang

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Здравствуйте! На wp сайте при деактивации плагина polylang на всех страницах пропадает контент, кроме хедера, но в самом хедере половина элементов тоже не отображается. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Есть какие-то мысли на этот счет? Может проблема в теме? Менять тему пробовал, в ней отображается чуть больше контента, но пишет что страница не найдена. Но основная проблема в том, что мне нужна конкретно та тема, которая работает с включенным polylang. Если возникает вопрос зачем я его деактивирую, то ответ прост: чтобы установить wpml плагин, у которого в разы больший функционал, но одновременно их установить я не могу, так как они конфликтуют между собой и вызывают фатальную ошибку, а если polylang активировать после wpml, то и вовсе 500-я ошибка появляется.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается проблема действительно была в теме, в настройках темы в секции Header был селект-бокс языков, который естественно работал только при активированном polylang. Из-за него-то и не отображался весь контент, который был ниже.

Comment: у меня возникла та же проблема.... можете подробнее описать путь ее решения????